# Extracting two values from dataframe using third value

Tags: python, dataframe, extract

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  TYPE     VALUE 
1     h        45
1     l        50
2     g        60
2     h        99
2     l        65
3     h        11
3     l        13
3     k        22
```

I would need to extract ID and TYPE according to largest VALUE for each ID.

Ending up with

```
1     l
2     h
3     k
```

Just starting with Python and don't know even where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit or delete this it seems.

Comment: Edit or delete what, exactly?

Comment: Bad formating. It got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some pandas functions here, especially `groupby()`:

```
idx = df.groupby(['ID'])['VALUE'].transform(max) == df['VALUE']
df[idx]
```

Which yields

```
    ID  TYPE    VALUE
1   1   l       50
3   2   h       99
7   3   k       22
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df[df.groupby(['ID'])['VALUE'].idxmax()]

    ID  TYPE    VALUE
1   1   l       50
3   2   h       99
7   3   k       22
```